# When to use which trig identity?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

So I understand that $\sin^2\theta \equiv 1 - \cos^2 \theta$. I am doing homework problems for trigonometric integrals and sometimes they use this formula to put into the equation and sometimes they put $\sin^2{t}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{2t})$.

For what situations do I use each one? I believe there is more identities for $\text{sin}$ to go along with these as well. Let me know please.

Comment: You use the one that makes the final result appear as nice as possible. It's so dependent on what else is in the expression that the only general hint that exists is "If you don't know, guess, and if it was wrong, guess something else." We could stand around for days lising examples of when to use one over the other, but in the end, this hint is what matters, and it is how the author of your book knows which one to pick.

Comment: It might help if you post an example of each case, one in which we use the identity $\sin^2\theta +\cos^2 \theta = 1$ (like in the first case you list), and an example in which the identity $\sin^2 t= \frac 12(1-\cos 2t)$ is used.  Then perhaps you will receive a more specific answer.

Comment: Are there any trig "identities" which aren't just rearrangements of $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$?

Comment: @jameselmore I won't say that. Formula $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ can be considered at most as a definition of $sin$ when you know $cos$; but there are trigonometrical identities that are very far from this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we use the pythagorean identity when having $\cos$ is better than having $\sin$ and there are more trig functions floating around.  This may be beneficial when

- You want to make a u-substitution e.g. $\int\sin^3x\ dx=\int\sin x(1-\cos^2)\ dx$
- Can cancel some terms away using $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$.

Likewise, if $\sin$ is by itself in an integral, you'll want to use the double angle identity.  This usually helps to

- Reduce powers e.g. $\int\sin^4x\ dx$

You will notice that for integrals of the form $\int\sin^nx\ dx$, you'll want to apply the pythagorean identity if $n$ is odd to create a u-substitution scenario and if $n$ is even, you'll want to use the power reducing double angle identity **repeatedly** until all exponents are odd.  Then apply the pythagorean.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will stress the importance of the second of these formulas dealing with angle doubling or halving. I wish that you have already seen matrices, a fundamental tool for dealing with geometry in general and trigonometry in particular.

It is true to say that formulas

$$\tag{1}\cos^2{t}=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos{2t}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \sin^2{t}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{2t})$$

and their sister formulas:

$$\tag{2}\cos(2t)=\begin{cases}2\cos^2(t)-1\\1-2\sin^2(t)\\ \cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)\end{cases}   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \sin(2t)=2 \sin(t) \cos(t)$$

are, among, say, a dozen or two dozen trigonometric formulas, the most used, just because they involve doubling/halving of angles, an operation that is very often encountered.

- in Physics, for example in Optics.
- in Mathematics, let us take 2 examples in plane geometry (among many):

A) the matrix of the (orthogonal) symmetry with respect to line $y=\tan(t)x$ is:

$$\tag{*}S_t=\pmatrix{\cos(2t)& \ \ \sin(2t)\\\sin(2t)&-\cos(2t)}$$

(one can verify that $S_t$ an orthogonal matrix with $\det(S_t)=-1.$)

What is the interest of formula (*) ?

For example showing that the composition of two symmetries: $S_t$ followed by $S_{t'}$ is a rotation $R_{\alpha}$ with angle $\alpha = 2(t'-t)$, the **double** of the angle between the two axes of symmetry; almost instantaneous proof:

$$\tag{**}S_{t'}S_{t}=\pmatrix{\cos(2t')& \ \ \sin(2t')\\\sin(2t')&-\cos(2t')}\pmatrix{\cos(2t)& \ \ \sin(2t)\\\sin(2t)&-\cos(2t)}=\pmatrix{\cos(\alpha)& \ \ -\sin(\alpha)\\ \sin(\alpha)&\ \ \ \ \ \cos(\alpha)}$$

B) the reduction of conics.

Let us look for the change of variables that will transform the quadratic form

$$\tag{3}Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{into}  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ A'X^2\pm B'Y^2$$

(having no longer a "rectangle term").

Let us take the following change of variables, which amounts to a rotation $R_t$:

$$\tag{4}\binom{x}{y}=\pmatrix{\cos(t)& \ \ -\sin(t)\\\sin(t)&\ \ \ \  \ \cos(t)}\binom{X}{Y} \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \begin{cases}x=X \cos(t) - Y \sin(t)\\y=X \sin(t) + Y \cos(t) \end{cases}.$$

(with unknown $t$). Plugging (4) into (3) gives

$$A(X \cos(t) - Y \sin(t))^2+2B(X \cos(t) - Y \sin(t))(X \sin(t) + Y \cos(t))+C(X \sin(t) + Y \cos(t))^2 $$

$$=\left(...\right) \,X^2 + 
  \left( 2B(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t))-(A-C)2cos(t)\sin(t)
     \right) \,X\,Y +  \left( ...
     \right) \,Y^2$$

(where the dotted coefficients are unimportant at this step).

Suppressing "rectangle" term $XY$ amounts to find $t$ such that

$$ 2B(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t))-(A-C)2cos(t)\sin(t)=0$$

Expression that can be transformed into:

$$ 2B\cos(2t)-(A-C)\sin(2t)=0  \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \tan(2t)=\dfrac{2B}{A-C}$$

> $$\iff \ \ \ t=\frac12 atan\left(\dfrac{2B}{A-C}\right)\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$$

It has been possible to find this "unique" value of $t$ thanks to formulas (2)!